# Vert.x Kafka not adhering to RxJava thread assignment?

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x, reactivex

Given the following code:

```
kafkaConsumer
  .rxSubscription()
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .map(s -> {
    logger.info("Mapping on Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return s;
   })
  .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
  .subscribe(
     set -> {
       logger.info("Subscribing on Thread: " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
   });
```

where kafkaConsumer is a Vert.x KafkaConsumer, I expect that the

```
.map(s -> {
  logger.info("Mapping on Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
  return s;
})
```

would happen on the Reactive IO Thread. However, it executes on the Vert.x event-loop Thread. When I run the following test class, the same scenario runs the map method on the IO thread as expected.

```
public class ThreadTesting {

public static void main(String args[]) {
  Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
  Observable.fromArray(new String[] {"start"})
    .flatMapSingle(s -> method1())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map(
        s -> {
          System.out.println("mapping 2 on Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          return s.concat(method2());
        })
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribe(
        str -> {
          System.out.println("Subscribing on Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        },
        onError -> {
          onError.printStackTrace();
        });
 }

 public static Single<String> method1() {
   System.out.println("Executing method 1 on Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
   AsyncResultSingle<String> vertxSingle = new AsyncResultSingle<>(
      h -> {
         h.handle(Future.succeededFuture("method 1 string"));
      });
    return vertxSingle;
 }

 public static String method2() {
   System.out.println("Executing method 2 on Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
   return "method 2 String";
 }
}
```

What causes this discrepancy in Thread execution to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The Vert.x `KafkaConsumer` emits items asynchronously on an event-loop thread, even if you subscribed to it on the `io` scheduler.

In your snippet, you try to force items to be emitted on the `computation` scheduler. It works, but not on the observable you expect: it applies to the observable returned by the `map` operation.

If you want `map` to operate on the `computation` scheduler, you need to apply the `observeOn` operator *before*:

```
kafkaConsumer
  .rxSubscription()
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
  .map(s -> {
    logger.info("Mapping on Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return s;
   })
  .subscribe(
     set -> {
       logger.info("Subscribing on Thread: " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
   });
```

Comment: I understand why the `map` function does not operate on the `computation` thread in my first code snippet. However what I don't understand is why the `map` function DOESN'T happen on the `io` thread. The `rxSubscription` method actually does happen on the `io` thread for me. The second code snippet I provided does the same thing in which the the `subscribeOn` method is called on an `AsyncResultSingle` (that's what `rxSubscribe` returns) and then maps immediately after. In that second code snipping the `map` function after the `subscribeOn` DOES happen on the `io` thread.

Comment: From the link you added:

    `just("Some String") // Computation
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // note the different order
  .map(str -> str.length()) // Computation
  .map(length -> 2 * length) // Computation
  .subscribe(number -> Log.d("", "Number " + number));// Computation`

I understand what is _supposed_ to happen. However in my initial code snippet, the `map` function immediately following the `subscribeOn` call is **not** on the `io` thread as all documentation would suggest it would be. Hence my original question of _why_.

Comment: `subscribeOn` defines the scheduler used to subscribe to an `Observable`. If this `Observable` is "synchronous", the items will be emitted on this scheduler. But if the `Observable` is "asynchronous", the items can be emitted on a completely different thread. In our case, the event loop used by the Kafka consumer. That is why there is the `observeOn` operator, to make sure items are emitted on a specific scheduler.